# A state meaning "not disposed"

Tags: single-word-requests

> If you dispose of an object, its state becomes "disposed".
>
> If the object has not yet been disposed of, it is called...

The obvious word would be "undisposed". However, I am seeking a positive state, without prefixes.

Comment: Do you mean *disposed **of***?

Comment: @Kris: Hm, yes. So there is no option for one word?

Comment: It seems like a doomed request when you ask for "without prefixes". *Dis-*, *with-* and *pre-* are prefixes, for example.

Comment: I'd love to be a smartass and say **indisposed**.

Comment: I think there are too many "potentially correct" answers here, so the question is POB. FQIW, I suggest ***retained, preserved***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best word to use would depend on your context. Here are some examples...

Current

Active

Live

Effective

Running

Added

Defined

Included

Perhaps some indication about where you want to use this word may help.

Answer (score 0):

To which, depending on context, you could add: *retained*

- Did you dispose of the billing statements?
- No, I retained them for our records.